# How to document different contents of files that have same name using sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx

I have a python project that has a structure as follows:

```
- dir_1
    - base.py
- dir_2
    - base.py
```

Both "base.py" files have different contents in them. But when I'm documenting using sphinx, the contents of the latest "base.py" file/module is being documented 
for both files.

My path entries in conf.py are as follows:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('\dir_1'))

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('\dir_2'))
```

How can I document the files' own contents without changing the file names?